# JAVA Else without if?

Tags: java

I have this code for an assignment. When I compile it, I get

```
grades.java:18: error: 'else' without 'if'
    else
    ^
1 error
```

Here is the code:

```
public class grades
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int gradeone=75;
        int gradetwo=80;
        int testscore= ((gradeone + gradetwo)/2);
        char grade;
        System.out.println("\n" + "your test score is" + testscore);
        if(testscore >= 90 )
      grade='A';
    elseif(testscore >= 80 );
      grade='B';
    elseif(testscore >= 70 );
      grade='C';
    elseif(testscore >= 65 );
      grade='D';
    else
      grade='F';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not Java. There's no such thing as `elseif`. You will want to read the [intro tutorial on use of if and else statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). Please check out the link as it will explain all.

Comment: Also, for emphasis, please be aware that, while semi-colons immediately after a conditional are legal, it will result in behavior you may not expect - namely, the conditional will be considered 'empty' (ie - if there was a semi-colon immediately after the last `else`, `grade` would _always_ be set to `'F'`

Comment: "elseif" has nothing to do with Java. There are people who try to adopt this notion in Java or C...but its just dangerous construct "else if" without any braces in between...that results in headaches to maintain code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already mentioned the syntax is ***else if*** - mind the space.

Moreover, I *highly recommend* you stick to conventional coding style until you become more confident in your skills.

A) For now, use brace syntax when using blocks and statements. Your code will be more readable and you will be able to identify your syntax errors easier. Though technically not required, you will be challenged trying to determine local variables and method scope without braces.

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int gradeOne = 75, gradeTwo = 80, testScore = ( ( gradeOne + gradeTwo ) / 2 );
    char grade;

    if( testScore >= 90 ) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if( testScore >= 80 ) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if( testScore >= 70 ) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if( testScore >= 65 ) {
        grade = 'D';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
    }
    System.out.println( "\n" + "your test score is: " + testScore );
}
```

B) When your uncertain about the syntax refer to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html) for answers ...

Answer (score 2):

`else if` instenad of `elseif` and you shouldn't have `;` at the end of the `else if` lines.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon after `else if`.
This kind of bug happens because of the *empty statement*, it will execute the semi-colon if the condition meets, then execute the other code (`grade = 'B';`) w/o any evaluation, this will separate the `if` of the `else`

Comment: There's a bit more wrong than that though.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have operator `elseif`. You have to write `else if` instead. So, java compiler is confused with your code and cannot find relevant `if` to your `else`.

Answer (score 0):

put "else if" in place of elseif and remove the commas after the if expression. then your code becomes same as below which run perfectly :)

```
public class check {
    public static void main (String [] 
        int gradeone=75;
        int gradetwo=80;
        int testscore= ((gradeone + gradetwo)/2);
        char grade;
        System.out.println("\n" + "your test score is" + testscore);
        if(testscore >= 90 )
            grade='A';
        else if(testscore >= 80 )
            grade='B';
        else if(testscore >= 70 )
            grade='C';
        else if(testscore >= 65 )
            grade='D';
        else
            grade='F';    
}
```

Comment: I must say the code with "else if" is hard to read, comprehend and maintain. I'd stick to classic braces constructs like if () {} else {}